# Plotly: Annotate marker at the last value in line chart

Tags: python, annotations, plotly, linechart, plotly-python

I am trying to mark the last value of the line chart with a big red dot in plotly express python, could someone please help me?

I am successful in building the line chart but not able to annotate the dot.

Below is my dataframe and I want the last value in the dataframe to be annotated.

[image]

Below is the line chart created and I want my chart to be similar to the second image in the screenshot

[image]

Code I am working with:

```
fig = px.line(gapdf, x='gap', y='clusterCount', text="clusterCount")
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could overlay an additional trace for the last data point with `plotly.graph_objects`:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

gapdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'clusterCount': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'gap': [-15.789, -14.489, -13.735, -13.212, -12.805, -12.475, -12.202, -11.965]
})

fig = px.line(gapdf, x='gap', y='clusterCount')

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[gapdf['gap'].iloc[-1]],
                         y=[gapdf['clusterCount'].iloc[-1]],
                         text=[gapdf['clusterCount'].iloc[-1]],
                         mode='markers+text',
                         marker=dict(color='red', size=10),
                         textfont=dict(color='green', size=20),
                         textposition='top right',
                         showlegend=False))

fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white',
                  xaxis=dict(linecolor='gray', mirror=True),
                  yaxis=dict(linecolor='gray', mirror=True))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion from gflavia works perfectly well.
But you can also set up an extra trace and associated text by addressing the elements in the figure directly instead of the data source like this:

```
fig.add_scatter(x = [fig.data[0].x[-1]], y = [fig.data[0].y[-1]])
```

#### Plot 1

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

gapdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'clusterCount': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    'gap': [-15.789, -14.489, -13.735, -13.212, -12.805, -12.475, -12.202, -11.965]
})

fig = px.line(gapdf, x='gap', y='clusterCount')

fig.add_scatter(x = [fig.data[0].x[-1]], y = [fig.data[0].y[-1]],
                     mode = 'markers + text',
                     marker = {'color':'red', 'size':14},
                     showlegend = False,
                     text = [fig.data[0].y[-1]],
                     textposition='middle right')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. Note, if you have several plots, e.g. a facet graph, you could make a loop `for d in fig.data`, and add `xaxis=d.xaxis, yaxis=d.yaxis`, so that the annotations appear on the correct plot.