# Plotly: How to annotate end of multiple lines with text and marker colors that match the lines?

Tags: python, plotly

The post [Plotly: Annotate marker at the last value in line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66184311/plotly-annotate-marker-at-the-last-value-in-line-chart/66190438#66190438)
shows how to annotate end of lines with text and an individual marker. But how can you do the same thing for multiple lines and at the same time set the associated text and markers to match the color of all lines?

#### Example plot:

[image]

#### Code with sample dataset:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.line(df, 
                 x = 'date',
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'date'],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 title = 'Stocks', 
             )

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can address the features of each trace and build new traces for your end markers and text through:

```
for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    fig.add_scatter(x=[d.x[-1]], y = [d.y[-1]], [...])
```

If you've specified colors when building your figure you can also retrieve trace colors and set colors for markers and fonts like this:

```
textfont = dict(color=d.line.color),
marker = dict(color = d.line.color, size = 12)
```

#### Plot:

[image]

The figure was being a *bit* crowded so I dropped one of the stocks. I also made room for the annotations by changing the position of the legend through `fig.layout.legend.x = -0.3`

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
df = df.drop('AMZN', axis = 1)
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.line(df, 
                 x = 'date',
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'date'],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 title = 'Stocks', 
             )

# move legend
fig.layout.legend.x = -0.3

# add traces for annotations and text for end of lines
for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    fig.add_scatter(x=[d.x[-1]], y = [d.y[-1]],
                    mode = 'markers+text',
                    text = d.y[-1],
                    textfont = dict(color=d.line.color),
                    textposition='middle right',
                    marker = dict(color = d.line.color, size = 12),
                    legendgroup = d.name,
                    showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

Comment: How can I connect these scatter markers to the main lines? For example, when I click on the legend to remove a line, I want the annotation to be removed too. Right now line and point with annotation are "disconnected" objects on the graph.

Comment: @MikhailShevelev Good question. It sould be posibble to sort out through [Grouped Legend Items](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend-items). I'll take a closer look later tonight.

Comment: @MikhailShevelev Just include `legendgroup = d.name`.

Comment: Thanks Vestland, I love your code. if there are multiple subplots with secondary y, how to modify your code to accommodate these? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this @vestland , Is there a way to extend this to only annotate the last n points ...say the last weeks worth of data when we are looking at a months data?

Comment: @Ananth That's a good question! Please consider asking that in a new post, and I'm sure one of use in here will be able to work out an approach!

Comment: Just done  - thanks @vestland

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209078/plotly-annotating-the-last-weeks-data-when-visualising-at-the-last-month-year