# Plotly : How to enable text label in line graph for the last value?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a graph where the line graph should show the value of only the last element in some beautiful formating.

[line graph with no text at end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S36FD.png)

Now the current method of the text shows for all elements and is a straight text that creates a lot of collisions with different lines in the same graph and looks clumsy.

Will be very nice to achieve something as mentioned in the below image.

[desired line graph with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2LqR.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190574/plotly-how-to-annotate-end-of-multiple-lines-with-text-and-marker-colors-that-m) solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, @vestland for answering, This does show the text for the last line but creates one more problem now, that is it creates a new scatter, and because of that when I try to hide the lines from the legend, the dot that is generated because of the scatter remains there.

I need a way so that when I hide a line via legend it also hides the dot as well for the same.

Answer (score 4):

This is now handled through:

```
legendgroup = d.name
```

#### Plot 1: All

[image]

#### Plot 2: Deselect GOOG in the legend and see that the marker disappears as well:

[image]

#### Complet code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
df = df.drop('AMZN', axis = 1)
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.line(df, 
                 x = 'date',
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'date'],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 title = 'Stocks', 
             )

# move legend
fig.layout.legend.x = -0.3

# add traces for annotations and text for end of lines
for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    fig.add_scatter(x=[d.x[-1]], y = [d.y[-1]],
                    mode = 'markers+text',
                    text = d.y[-1],
                    textfont = dict(color=d.line.color),
                    textposition='middle right',
                    marker = dict(color = d.line.color, size = 12),
                    legendgroup = d.name,
                    showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

Comment: If you're dealing with a facet plot with multiple subplots, add `xaxis=d.xaxis, yaxis=d.yaxis` to `fig.add_scatter` so the label is added to the correct subplot. Default behavior is to add all labels to the 1st one.