# How to annotate the last weeks data when visualising at the last month / year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-express

I am aware that the last point can be annotated in plotly as per the code below

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# data
df = px.data.stocks()
df = df.drop('AMZN', axis = 1)
colors = px.colors.qualitative.T10

# plotly
fig = px.line(df, 
                 x = 'date',
                 y = [c for c in df.columns if c != 'date'],
                 template = 'plotly_dark',
                 color_discrete_sequence = colors,
                 title = 'Stocks', 
             )

# move legend
fig.layout.legend.x = -0.3

# add traces for annotations and text for end of lines
for i, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    fig.add_scatter(x=[d.x[-1]], y = [d.y[-1]],
                    mode = 'markers+text',
                    text = d.y[-1],
                    textfont = dict(color=d.line.color),
                    textposition='middle right',
                    marker = dict(color = d.line.color, size = 12),
                    legendgroup = d.name,
                    showlegend=False)

fig.show()
```

However, can this be extended to show the annotations for the last weeks data when viewing the last month/years data?

I looked at the explanation mentioned here and this works to annotate the last point

[Plotly: How to annotate end of multiple lines with text and marker colors that match the lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190574/plotly-how-to-annotate-end-of-multiple-lines-with-text-and-marker-colors-that-m)

But I wanted to extend this further

Cheers
Ananth

Comment: What you want to do is find the last week? Then you could use the date column to find the largest year and week number and get the index of that row.

Comment: Thanks - I had the same thought but wanted some sample code to test ...I have tried a few options too but they arent working.